# What is the optimal strategy to invest a limited resource in N uncertain options?

Tags: normal-distribution, risk, decision-theory

Suppose I have a £100 to invest in 2 options.  Each option has a expected value, but the value is unknown.

Option A has the highest average expected value, but a bigger uncertainty range.

[image: Two options with normally distributed uncertain returns here]

If we just looked at means we would invest everything in A.

What circumstances would cause a mixed investment strategy?

Comment: what do you mean by "optimal"?

Comment: @shimao - I guess I mean 'what definitions of optimal make this an interesting question'?  
What would cause you to legitimately invest in B over A (or a Mix)

Comment: This seems to be an related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/347650/26948

Comment: Suppose that losing all your money would be catastrophic to you, that A has an appreciable chance of losing it all, and B has almost no chance: which option would you chose?  Simple *gedankenexperimenten* like this show why *how you value the potential gains and losses* is an essential part of the analysis.  This idea is the basis of online retirement calculators that suggest what mixture of investments to make depending on how much money you need to have and by when. The thread indicated by @shimao is indeed relevant. In practice (unfortunately) stocks never behave independently!

Answer (score 1):

One important consideration is your risk tolerance.

For concreteness, let's say that the above curves represent the distributions of the potential eventual value of a £1 investment. For option A, it looks like the expected value is £1.5, versus £1.3 for option B. Yes, if all you cared about was the expected value, you would choose option A.

But if the dashed vertical lines represent 95% confidence limits, it also appears that you have about a 2.5% chance of the eventual value under option A being £0.5 or lower, in which case you've lost half of your investment. Under option B, although your expected value is lower than for option A, a similarly improbable (2.5%) scenario would be an eventual value of about £0.95, or only a 5% loss of your investment.

So what's your tradeoff between risk and reward? In many cases, your particular tradeoff might mean a mixed investment strategy is best. That way you can protect some of your investment under option B while hoping for the possibility of higher yields under option A from the rest of your £100 investment.